Parental leave during trial period
As a kind of follow up to a previous question of mine, I have finally found a new job.
It has been confirmed that I am the company's #1 pick for the position, and I will have the final interview soon, where we will mostly discuss details about the contract and so on.
According to German law, we have 14 months of paid parental leave ("Elternzeit") in total.
I had my child, and took my first month of parental leave during the summer. My partner is currently on parental leave for 12 months.  Our plan is that I take the remaining month of parental leave when my partner's finishes. That would be next year in July.
This has already been approved by my current company.
However, now it turns out I very likely won't be working for this company anymore come next summer. I have a notice period of 3 months, so if I hand in my resignation during the month of November (which I very probably will), I will start my new job in March next year. The standard probation period duration in Germany is 6 months, which means my planned second month of Elternzeit would fall in that probation period.
How to best handle this? I feel like this is a bit of a different situation from my last question because, this parental leave has been approved by the State already (I had to get my current company's confirmation in writing, and send it to the State to get approved, so it's kind of "set in stone" now as far as the State is concerned), and also, it is almost sure that I will actually accept this offer and start this new job.
What are my rights here? Of course I want to be upfront and honest to my perspective new employer.

No matter what remember you will have other jobs.  You will never again have that time with your child.

The best way to handle the situation is to clarify it with the new employer and get approval in writing (e-mail at this stage, a formal document after onboarding) before signing the new contract.
Your new employer must approve your Elternzeit if you inform them at least 7 weeks before start. And for reasonable employers a one month Elternzeit should not be a problem. But they can also terminate you during the first six months with little restrictions, so it is best to clear things up before joining.
First clarify things with your new prospective employer and then inform the Elterngeldstelle. They will inform you of what documentation you need to submit.

regarding approval: Elternzeit does not need employer approval, you just have to tell them 7 weeks before. So legally, employer cannot decline.

@KarstenKoop good to know. I'll change my answer.

"the best way is to get approval before signing the new contract" -- i think this claim needs to be supported. if the new employer is legally obligated to provide leave, then it may be in the employee's best interest to sign the contract before disclosing the need (provided the disclosure window can still be met).

@WoodrowBarlow OP will be in the 6 months probation period during their Elternzeit. This means it is fairly easy for the employer to end the contract if they want to. Of course the can't do it because of Elternzeit, but during probation they can just say that it was a bad fit and that's it. So OP should be honest and upfront about their Elternzeit. The employer shouldn't have a problem with that. If they do, better to find out early and leave.

@quarague that makes sense! i think that context is what's missing from this answer.

Just bring it up in your next interview: "I currently have parental leave planned for July next year, would you be able to accommodate that?"
Based on their answer you can decide what you find most important: switch jobs and don't take parental leave in July next year if they can't or won't accommodate you, or you can stick with your current employer at least until after your planned parental leave. Or a third option: find a job at a different company where they will accommodate your planned parental leave.
I have to admit I'm not aware of how this is arranged in Germany. If your new employer can accommodate you, it's highly likely HR has experience with this so I'd just ask to reach out to them about this matter. It's unlikely you're the first person in Germany to switch jobs while having parental leave planned and approved.
